# libMagickCore.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

**UPDATE:**

gem install rmagick solved the problem.

=====================================

After upgrading my ubuntu to 12.10 when I run my rails application it gives an error

> libMagickCore.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/pramod/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/RMagick2.so

below path exists in my system.

> /home/pramod/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/RMagick2.so

I'm new to linux and don't have much idea on how to solve it. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you upgrade you can lose the reference to library file in a compiled gem. To resolve this just recompile the gem (the rmagick gem in this case). Depending on your server setup you can do this with
`gem pristine rmagick`
or
`bundle exec gem pristine rmagick` when using bundler.

Comment: for whatever reason, I had to do a full `bundle exec gem uninstall rmagick` then reinstall to get it to work.

Answer (score 7):

Add the following to .bashrc any try again

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

if, the above command does not work means the install ImageMagick to configured with rmagick.
Try,

```
   gem uninstall rmagick
   gem install rmagick
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me (although also tried export and gem reinstall solutions, which might have also helped, but didn't do the complete job...):

```
ldconfig /usr/local/lib
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, upgrading to version 2.15.3 worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had all the native libraries installed under **vendor/bundle**, because we use `bundle install --deployment` on our servers.

In this setup neither `gem pristine rmagick` nor `gem uninstall rmagick; gem install vendor/cache/rmagick-<version>.gem` helped.

I had to remove **vendor/bundle** and do a **bundle install --deployment** again `rm -r vendor/bundle; bundle install --deployment`.

These commands should be run from the root directory of the rails application.